# file_get_contents() returns an empty array and stream_context_create() returns Resource id #8 while recaptcha V2 upgrade

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am working in PHP to upgrade recaptcha from V1 to V2.
Below is the code that we are using to send the request via POST method and trying to read the response to verify if captcha entered is correct or not.
But we are facing two issues
1. stream_context_create() returns Resource id #8
2. file_get_contents() returns an emptpy array
Please suggested I had spend two weeks on this issue and now is the deadline
Below is the code snippet.

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
                         array(
                                'secret'    =>  $privkey,
                                'response' => $response,
                                 'remoteip'  =>  $remoteip
                                )
                        );

        $opts = array('http' =>
                 array(
                        'method'  => 'POST',
                        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'content' => $postdata
            )
        );
        $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
        print "Context   is " . $context . "<br>";
        $response = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', false, $context);

        if(implode(null,$response)==null){
            print "File_get_contents Array is empty ";
        }else{
            print "File_get_contents Array has value";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` returns a string so using `implode` is not correct way to do this. If you really want to see response just `var_dump($response)` then you will  see .

Second `$context` is a  [resource variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)  which holding a reference to an external resource.

```
  $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
        //print "Context   is " . $context . "<br>";
  $response = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', false, $context);
  var_dump($response) ; //Now you can see response
```